# Getting xmlhttp response empty when json object accessed through server path

Tags: javascript, xml, spring-mvc

I have a js function which goes to a spring controller class returning a json object with data like :

```
 {"prop1":"val1",
 "prop2":"val2"}
```

The js function is something like :

```
 accessValue(a,b,c){

  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
       alert("This works 1");
       xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
           alert("This works 2");
              if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) { 
                  alert("This works 3" + xmlhttp.status);//line 1
              if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                   var jsonobj = JSON.parse(this.responseText); //line 1
                   alert("Hi ");
                   document.getElementById(b).innerHTML = jsonobj.prop1;
                   document.getElementById(c).innerHTML = jsonobj.prop2;
                   console.log(jsonobj.prop2);
              }
              else if (xmlhttp.status == 400) {
                    alert('There was an error 400');
              }

       }
     };
     xmlhttp.open("GET", a + "--spring controller class path --");
     xmlhttp.send(null);

}
```

In the function parameters b and c are div ids which I want to update with the data which comes in the json object. Parameter a is a URL which is appended with spring path of the controller class, this class returns json object which runs perfectly fine.

At line 1, I am getting status for xmlhttp.status as 0 which is empty response. After searching online I found out that this may happen bcz the file may be accessed locally properly but through server its not happening. The same code when used on localhost works great. Is there a way I could access this spring controller returned json object on server using proper http url and parse the data to update my divs ?

Comment: Is the used URL subject to the SOP?

Comment: the url is a server on which the spring path is used to get json object

Comment: Then the spring server must send CORS headers if you want to overcome the SOP.

Comment: Thanks @Dormilich Thats what I did.